# How to Divide two columns in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have disk capacities stored in 2 columns as CAPACITY_TOTAL and CAPACITY_USED. I need to present % utilization for which I need to divide CAPACITY_USED by CAPACITY_TOTAL as CAPACITY_USED/CAPACITY_TOTAL * 100.
I am using below Query:

```
select CAPACITY_USED / CAPACITY_TOTAL from TableName
```

which gives below error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-801, SQLSTATE=22012, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.15.82
```

I have casted my columns to decimal but even that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure `CAPACITY_TOTAL` is always greater than `0`? `SQLSTATE=22012` suggests division by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so `SQLSTATE=22012` means you're trying to *divide by zero*. Apparently some of your rows contain nulls or zeroes in `CAPACITY_TOTAL` column and db fails to calculate the formula.

Try this query for better results:

```
SELECT CASE CAPACITY_TOTAL 
            WHEN 0    THEN 0
            WHEN NULL THEN 0
            ELSE CAPACITY_USED / CAPACITY_TOTAL
       END AS UTILIZATION
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

You may want to put some other meaningful return values for zeroes / nulls.

Alternatively, skip rows, where `CAPACITY_TOTAL` is null or zero:

```
SELECT CAPACITY_USED / CAPACITY_TOTAL AS UTILIZATION
  FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE CAPACITY_TOTAL IS NOT NULL
   AND CAPACITY_TOTAL > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Error code 801 means your query was trying to divide by zero.

```
select CAPACITY_USED / CAPACITY_TOTAL from TableName
where CAPACITY_TOTAL IS NOT NULL and CAPACITY_TOTAL <> 0
```

Comment: `NVL` won't solve division by zero. It will only help against nulls.